# User with only per-site meta profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta, russian-stackoverflow

I found a user that have only [Meta profile](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/199432/stackoverfollow). Trying to open main profile via [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199432/stackoverfollow) on the meta profile page gives 404 error.

I don't think this is normal. [User](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/187185/stackoverfollow) is currently banned in chat for 189 days:

> [image: chat-user]

Parent user link refers to already mentioned 404 page.

Comment: They **did** have an account on the main site, but it was deleted (not that I know why), as can be seen from this [migration history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/570446/revisions). The question now: *why didn't their meta account get deleted too?*

Comment: Why can't I see the English version for that? Why Russian? Is Russian SO a different site altogether?

Comment: @NVZ yes, there is a version of Stack Overflow is several different languages these days, Russian is one of them. There is no "English version" of these sites, each is on its own, got its own users and posts, etc

Comment: @NVZ Stack Overflow in Russian is a part of Stack Exchange network. One of localized versions of StackOverflow, like Portuguese, Spanish and Japanese.

Comment: Anyway, my best guess is that a CM nuked the user's accounts via some automated process (I see this done to spammers quite often), and that process just skips/ignores meta accounts, probably a bug/overlook as they never expected spammers to have meta accounts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's what my report is about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That user deleted their own SOru profile back in September of last year. Clearly *something* went wrong and the meta profile didn't get removed. Not much point in digging into the "why" since so much time has passed, but if you see other orphaned meta profiles, please let me know.

Comment: Just being picky as usual, but if nothing was fixed, why [tag:status-completed]? (if it can't be reproduced, think no-repro fits better)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I removed the profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no repro after fixing :)

Comment: @AdamLear There appear to be [about 430 other orphaned meta profiles, network-wide](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/671360).

Comment: @JasonC Hm. I spot-checked a few and it looks like some are left behind as a result of a deletion, some as a result of a merge. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code (then again, if there was something obvious wrong, we'd most likely see a lot more than 430 profiles). I'm not sure this is anything to really worry about, but I'll try to dig deeper if/when time allows.

Comment: @AdamLear It's since ballooned to 1,419. Can you please [re-investigate this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347277/having-an-account-on-meta-but-not-on-the-main-site-and-vice-versa)?