# Incomplete deletion of user account?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

(I asked this question in [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23311/incomplete-deletion-of-user-account) around 3 1/2 years ago, but there has been no response.)

While browsing old questions in Mathematics Meta, I came across a user with an undeleted [meta user account](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/23452/gigili) but with a (seemingly) non-existent [main user account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23452/gigili).  I was under the impression that the creation of a meta user account requires the existence of a main user account.  This implies that the main user account was deleted after the meta user account was created.

> When a main user account is deleted, then shouldn't the associated meta user account also be deleted?

Comment: Curious, it seems that the user *does* have a [main account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/181853/gigili), but it's disassociated from the meta one. Perhaps that should be the question - how it could happen.

Comment: [It’s happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295869/323179).

Comment: @WeareMonica., the meta account for the main account you link to is https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/181853/gigili

Comment: @Laurel, thanks for the link.  I searched the site before I asked this question, but I wasn't able to see the one you linked to.

Comment: @WeareMonica. Their accounts were merged. The merge process just fell over somewhere and forgot to delete the Meta profile. Based on the query in the previous question linked here, the number of cases has almost doubled, with one as recent as October 24, 2019.