# Having an account on meta but not on the main site and vice versa?

Tags: support, user-accounts, per-site-meta, deleted-accounts

Under what circumstances can a user have an account only on (site).meta.stackexchange.com and not on (site).stackexchange.com?

And vice versa.

The thing is that I saw a user account on math.meta and it was 'complete' in the sense that it had activity and 3k reputation. Then I clicked on the main math.stack icon and it displayed a "page not found" error.

I've never witnessed this situation before. What I know is that once an account is deleted on main, it is also deleted on meta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User with only per-site meta profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295869/user-with-only-per-site-meta-profile)

Comment: @MarkKirby Half. The vice versa part is not addressed. Thank you for the link

Comment: I think a user who never visited a per site meta just does not have a profile there, like this one https://askubuntu.com/users/1075542/sabuj-maity or this one https://stackoverflow.com/users/2838922/alexandre-vandermonde They have to visit the meta to create a profile.

Comment: It is known that in account merges / deletes things might break as those don't run in a db transaction. In some corner cases this give weird effects, either between main/meta or main/chat profiles. Needs a dev to sort out.

Comment: @rene Indeed. According to moderator animuson's comment here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337939/incomplete-deletion-of-user-account?noredirect=1&lq=1 seems like is a merge problem.

Comment: @MarkKirby That question is marked completed, as it was specifically asking about the specific case there, and it was manually resolved for that one user. This is a different user's case.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Sure but I think the answer there still applies here. The reason it happened is the same, even if it is two different cases.

Comment: @MarkKirby Not necessarily. As pointed out here, there's another, different reason why it may have happened.